# Basic parallelization under sequential consistency

Tags: parallel-processing, sequential, sequential-workflow

I have a problem with 2 processors that perform the following operations:

```
**Processor 1**                 **Processor 2**
(1a) print x                       (2a)x=1
(1b) x=2                           (2b) print x
```

They ask what values will be printed. The solution provided is (0,1), (0,2), (1,1) and (1,2).

My question is: how do you obtain those values?

Comment: So long as statement `1a` is executed before `1b` and `2a` before `2b` the statements can occur in any sequence.  Write down some of those sequences, see what gets printed.

Comment: Now i understand, with the sequence 1a 2a 1b 2b, i obtain (0,2) which is one of the solutions, thanks!!